# Openshift WildFly custom system properties and datasource definitions do not survive an app restart

Tags: openshift

My application needs EclipseLink, thus after I created my WildFly cart I ssh to the account and do:

```
jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=$OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_PORT
/system-property=eclipselink.archive.factory:add(value=org.jipijapa.eclipselink.JBossArchiveFactoryImpl)
```

the system property is defined fine. However it is lost after

```
ctl_app restart
```

It is the same for a newly defined datasource.

It looks like Openshift resets everything and deploys the cart from scratch.
Any opinions why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to make configuration changes is to update the standalone.xml configuration file that exists inside your OpenShift application .openshift/config directory.
Every OpenShift application has .openshift directory that contains configuration files that you can update. Everytime you push the source code OpenShift takes your standalone.xml file and apply it. So when you restart the application your changes are overridden. Refer to documentation https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SystemProperties to learn how to add system properties to standalone.xml

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried your suggestion and applied my changes to app-deployments/current/repo/.openshift/config/standalone.xml. Then, manually restarted the app with rhc app restart -a <appname>. However this did not work. Any guidance on what I might be missing?

Comment: Finally got it. I should have changed $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.openshift/config/standalone.xml (or the one in eclipse). It's working allright now. Thanks Shekhar for the answer.

Comment: It might help to summarize the actual changed needed to standalone.xml here. That way it will stay readable even if the target site goes down.